# Ubuntu on a live cd wont let me access the installed HDD

Tags: permissions

I am using a live cd running Ubuntu 14.04 and when I try to access my hard drives /media/(Myname) it telling me that persmission is denied. Even when i could view the files earlier. How can i fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would deny you access now that you have it mounted. What you can do is unmount it a mount it again with read/write permission.
Something like

```
sudo umount /media/DRIVE_NAME
sudo mount -o rw,remount /dev/DISK_PARTITION /media/DRIVE_NAME
```

In some cases I've noticed that even though I'm able to access the partition, see the files, and open them, I am still not allows to write to them. A hackish workaround would also be to open nautilus as root

```
sudo nautilus
```

Although in that scenario you are not really fixing the problem but going around it, if you need constant access to the partition you probably want to look under /etc/fstab and understand the line about the partition you are trying to access.

Hope this helps!